# Why does Client Height value doesn't apply to other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want my sidebar to have spacing from top equal to header's height. When I use
`clientHeight`in js, although it returns the right value when I print it via `alert()`, it doesn't apply to other elements as `marginTop` or `top` value. (`Position` was included while using `top`).

HTML

```
<body onload="sidenav_height()">
 ...
</body>
```

JS

```
function sidenav_height(){
  var height = document.getElementById("header").clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.marginTop = height;
}
```

Comment: The value of `style.marginTop` needs an unit, `.clientHeight` returns a number only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please change

```
function sidenav_height(){
  var height = document.getElementById("header").clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.marginTop = height+"px";
}
```